# srtm30 image: some are grayscale some are black & white

Tags: dem

I downloaded these DEM files, http://www.dgadv.com/srtm30/
srtm30 globe. I open the DEM files in Multispec. Some of them are black and white, some are automatically grayscale.

How do I get them all in grayscale?

(attaching image to explain)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if you can try the answer seen here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10408/1297 and see if it helps any.

Comment: Hi SaultDon, yes i have did some experiment on photoshop; adjusting levels, brightness/ darkness does help abit. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Well, i did it in Qgis. Import srtm data, then properties-->colormatp=gray, make sure to set current to stretch to minmax. Apply. Then you export as image from file menu.

Good enough?